# Creating a user object in Django: why are first_name and last_name both stored as (u'Name',)?

Tags: python, django

I've created a user registration form, and for some reason the first_name and last_name fields are stored within (u'',). How do I prevent this?

views.py (unrelated stuff omitted):

```
def register(request):           

   if request.method == 'POST':
         form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
         if form.is_valid():
             user = User.objects.create_user(
                     username=form.cleaned_data['username'],
                     email=form.cleaned_data['email'],
                     password=form.cleaned_data['password']
                     )
             user.first_name=form.cleaned_data['first_name'],
             user.last_name=form.cleaned_data['last_name'],
             user.save()
             userprofile, created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user = user)
             return HttpResponse("you have been successfully registered!")
```

models.py:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
     user = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

For instance, I register a user with the name Joe Bruin. The name is stored as (u'Joe',) (u'Bruin',). I figure something has gone wrong with form.cleaned_data, but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`first_name` and `last_name` are not stored within `u''`. The `u''` just means that the returned string is in unicode format. The default encoding in django is [unicode](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/unicode/). Take a look at what is actually stored in your database.

From [Django Docs General String Handling](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/unicode/#general-string-handling):

```
# Python 2 legacy:
my_string = "This is a bytestring"
my_unicode = u"This is an Unicode string"

# Python 3 or Python 2 with unicode literals 
from __future__ import unicode_literals

my_string = b"This is a bytestring"
my_unicode = "This is an Unicode string"
```

Notice how in Python 3 the default is unicode.

Comment: Thanks. What threw me off is that it seems to only occur with the names. How do I get it to format properly in a template? `{{ userprofile.user.first_name }}` leaves it in the unicode format.

Comment: `userprofile` is part of the context since I'm using a custom user model.

Comment: Did you remove the commas at the end of these lines?: `user.first_name=form.cleaned_data['first_name'],
             user.last_name=form.cleaned_data['last_name'],`

Comment: Yes, I did.  That seems to have fixed it.

Comment: Ok. The commas were making your `first_name` and `last_name` a tuple. When those variables are rendered in the template, a string representation of the tuple is what you will get. That's why you were getting (u'Joe',).

Answer (score 3):

You have trailing commas:

```
user.first_name=form.cleaned_data['first_name'],
user.last_name=form.cleaned_data['last_name'],
```

That makes them into tuples. You don't want that. Remove the trailing commas.

Comment: Thanks! Left those in from trying to pass them into `create_user`. Wish I had enough rep to upvote you.